# How to setTimeout while keeping current context?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Within a method of a JS object, I wish to call another of the object's methods (updateState), after a fixed period of time. Below is my current effort:

```js
setTimeout((function() {
    this.updateState("closed")
}).call(this), cycleOpenTime);
```

As the current context is necessary, I've tried to pass it through with the .call function, but this seems to break setTimeout (I think it's no longer treated as a function?).

Is there another way of achieving this?

(I'm working in Node.js if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method of `Function` prototype:

```
setTimeout((function() {this.updateState("closed")}).bind(this), cycleOpenTime);
```

Comment: isn't the OP explaining that he can't access the `updateState` function?

Comment: Note that full IE support for [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) did not appear until IE9.

Answer (score 3):

This is universal for old browsers (that does not support bind(); ):

```
var me = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    me.updateState("closed");
}, cycleOpenTime);
```

*You should learn something about **Closures in JS**.*